# Descrepencies in python matrix inverse calculation with date sorting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, matrix

I have a time series of returns and I need to calculate the covariance matrix and some measurements based on the covariance matrix.

But I find when I format the time, the result will be different from that without date formatting.

```
    #change the date format
    raw['date']=pd.to_datetime(raw['date'])
```

In particular, if you can access my [script](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jFrnzjHVbjNwFKFisOasJEFiaDlWNFvf/view?usp=share_link) and data files:

1. if we use [data-m3](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jG1HRIs7YNnBlkOylJ7waBMtktth1uXA/view?usp=share_link) to run the script, no matter if we change the date format in the third cell,  the result of delta_P2 is always the same.
2. if we use [data-m6](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10fKCkTotyaodPfTBvVq8EK8kfBVGb2u4/view?usp=share_link) or [data-m9](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jFt9_BnFXJTBEGtaV5AnHpum6LtJ-qKs/view?usp=share_link) to run the script, and if we change the date format in the third cell, the result of delta_P2 varies.
3. the structure of the three data files is quite similar, except for the number of observations.
4. I have a close look into the calculation of delta_P2, to find that the covariance matrix used are the same, but when do some matrix inverse, the result is different.

```
    # Calculate delta_P2
    delta_P2=gamma/2*((V21.values- 
    V20.values.dot(np.linalg.pinv(V00.values).dot(V01.values))).dot(I1)
                  +((V20.values- 
    V21.values.dot(np.linalg.pinv(V11.values).dot(V10.values))).dot(np.linalg.pinv(V00.values- 
    V01.values.dot(np.linalg.pinv(V11.values).dot(V10.values)))).dot(V02.values- 
    V01.values.dot(np.linalg.pinv(V11.values).dot(V12.values)))- 
    V20.values.dot(np.linalg.pinv(V00.values).dot(V02.values))).dot(I2)
                 
    +V21.values.dot(np.linalg.pinv(V11.values).dot(V10.values)).dot(np.linalg.pinv(V00.values- 
    V01.values.dot(np.linalg.pinv(V11.values).dot(V10.values)))).dot(V02.values- 
    V01.values.dot(np.linalg.pinv(V11.values).dot(V12.values))).dot(I2)
                 +V21.values.dot(np.linalg.pinv(V11.values- 
    V10.values.dot(np.linalg.pinv(V00.values).dot(V01.values)))).dot(V12.values- 
    V10.values.dot(np.linalg.pinv(V00.values).dot(V02.values))).dot(I2)
                 )
```

I understand that the matrix inverse in Python might be slightly different due to some reason. But I am more confused about why the error only occurs in some files, not all circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Python 3.11 with Pandas 2.1.3 and Numpy 1.26.2. I tried running your code with the different files and different date formats, and `delta_P2` printed the same results.

Are you still getting different values? How about updating Pandas and Numpy to latest version. Make sure the data you are transforming is the one you are expecting to be used as input.